# Perl code fails to match recursively (nested subs)

Tags: perl

The code below loops through folders in “/data/results” directory and matches each .vcf file name, located in a sub-folder (two levels down) to the content of a matrix_key file.

This seem to work only for the first folder.  I printed the content of each @matrix_key and it’s correct. The code always fails to match for the second folder.  Here is where it fails to match:: `if ( my $aref = first { index($sample_id, $_->[1]) != -1 } @matrix_key ) {`

I’ve tried to run one folder at a time and it work great.  I don’t understand why it fails when I put multiple folders in `/data/results/`? Could someone please suggest how to correct this issue? Thank you.

Here is an example of directory structure:

```
/data/results/
    TestFolder1/
        subfolder1/Variants/MD-14-11856_RNA_v2.vcf
        subfoder2/Variants/SU-16-16117_RNA_v2.vcf
        matrix.txt
        matrixkey.txt

    TestFolder2/
        subfolder1/Variants/SU-15-2542_v2.vcf
        subfolder2/Variants/SU-16-16117_v2.vcf
        matrix.txt
        matrixkey.txt
```

Example of `@matrix_key`:

```
Barcode        SampleName
barcode_003    SU-15-2542
barcode-005    MD-14-11856
barcode-002    SU-16-16117
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy qw(move);
use List::Util 'first';
use File::Find;
use File::Spec;
use Data::Dumper;

use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions 'splitdir';

my $current_directory = "/data/results";
my @dirs = grep { -d } glob '/data/results/*';

if (grep -d, glob("$current_directory/*")) {
    print "$current_directory has subfolder(s)\n";
}
else {
    print "there are no folders\n";
    die;
}

my %files;

my @matrix_key = (); 

for my $dir ( @dirs ) { 

    print "the directory is $dir\n";
    my $run_folder = (split '/', $dir)[3];
    print "the folder is $run_folder\n";

    my $key2 = $run_folder;

    # checks if barcode matrix and barcode summary files exist  

    #shortens the folder names and unzips them.

    #check if each sample is present in the matrix file for each folder.
    my $location = "/data/results/".$run_folder;

    my $matrix_key_file = "/data/results/".$run_folder."/matrixkey.txt";

    open my $key, '<', $matrix_key_file or die $!; # key file

    <$key>; # throw away header line in key file (first line)

    @matrix_key = sort { length($b->[1]) <=> length($a->[1]) } 
                  map [ split ], <$key>;
    close $key or die $!;

    print Dumper(@matrix_key) . "===\n\n";

    find({ wanted => \&find_vcf, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
    #find({ wanted => find_vcf, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
}

my $find_vcf = sub {
    #sub find_vcf {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;

    if ($F =~ /vcf$/ ) {
        print "$F\n";

        $F =~ m|([^/]+).vcf$| or die "Can't extract Sample ID";
        my $sample_id = $1; print "the short vcf name is: $sample_id\n";

        if ( my $aref = first { index($sample_id, $_->[1]) != -1 } @matrix_key ) {
            #the code fails to match sample_id to matrix_key
            #even though it's printed out correctly

            print "$sample_id \t MATCHES $aref->[1]\n";
            print "\t$aref->[1]_$aref->[0]\n\n";

        } else {
            # handle all other possible exceptions

            #print "folder name is $run_folder\n";

            die("The VCF file doesn't match the Summary Barcode file: $sample_id\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code fails here `if ( my $aref = first { index($sample_id, $_->[1]) != -1 } @matrix_key )` but $sample_id is correct and also dumper displays the correct  matrix_key file, yet it only works for the first folder  in /data/results. I have no clue why....Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would really help if you pinned down exactly where it fails. Could be the glob, could be something else, but there's a bunch of code here that someone would have to go down the whole hundred lines to check it out. Please also reformat it so that it's properly indented and so on. The way it is now, everything is shown as a regex from /zip$/ down.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format the code correctly so it's not in red.

Comment: Do you want me to shorten the code?  I thought it would help to see the whole script? Thanks

Comment: Well, it helps to isolate the error. Whatever it is, it must be reduced to one or a couple of lines. In the process of isolation, you might end up finding the solution yourself...

Comment: @jjmerelo the error occurs here `if ( my $aref = first { index($sample_id, $_->[1]) != -1 } @matrix_key )` I've printed both the sample_id and @matrix_key and the code should find a match but it fails for the second folder. Please help.

Comment: I've updated the code to isolate the error but still don't know what causes it. Thanks

Comment: I'm fairly new at perl myself, but my impression is that [nested `sub`s are tricky](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=696592).  In your shoes, I would move `find_vcf` out to the top-level scope, and make  `@matrix_key` a `my @matrix_key;` before `find_vcf` and the `for` loop.  After all, if `$sample_id` is correct but the `first` fails, `@matrix_key` is the only other piece of data in the `first` to experiment with!

Comment: ... And the same with `$location`.  Also, please rename one of `$matrix_key` and `@matrix_key` - don't use the same name for two different variables!

Comment: `move find_vcf out to the top-level scope` not sure what you mean by that? Also, I need to run find_vcf for each folder in /data/results directory so how can I take it out of the for loop?

Comment: I haven't looked closely, but any use of a named sub within a loop or another sub is a bug. Your issue can probably be fixed by changing to `my $find_vcf = sub { ... }; find({ wanted => $find_vcf, ...`.

Comment: `find({ wanted => find_vcf, no_chdir=>1}, $location);` doesn't compile. Could you please give a more complete example? thanks

Comment: Put `sub find_vcf { ... }` before the `for` loop.  You only have to define the function once, and then can call it multiple times.

Comment: Now I get the following error: `Undefined subroutine &main::find_vcf called at /usr/share/perl5/File/Find.pm lin                                                                                                                                                             e 691.`

Comment: you changed 
sub find_vcf 
to 
 my $find_vcg = sub { ... };
but the call is still { wanted => find_vcf }.

The function find_vcf is no longer declared.

Comment: @user3781528 I said `wanted => $find_vcf`, not `wanted => find_vcf`.

Comment: @user3781528  I edited your question, to fix (some of) inconsistent and excessive indentation and blank lines.  If you don't like that please click on `edited [time]` above my username and you'll see the edit versions.  Click on `rollback` under the previous version to restore it to what it had been.

Comment: Sorry, i spent several hours but couldnt get the reference to file: find: rule library to work, so i put it aside for a while. I need to find another way.

Comment: @user3781528  Sure -- but "another way" isn't a solution -- you need to find out why modules installed in a fairly standard location don't work.  (Then use some other way if you wish, by all means :)

Answer (score 2):

The posted code appears to be a bit complicated for the job.

Here is one way to do what I understand from the question. It uses [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find::Rule;
use List::Util 'any';

my $base_dir = '/data/results';    
my @dirs = File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(1)->directory->in($base_dir);

foreach my $dir (@dirs) 
{
    # Find all .vcx files anywhere in this dir or below
    my @vcx_files = File::Find::Rule->file->name('*.vcx')->in($dir);

    # Remove the path and .vcx extension
    my @names = map { m|.*/(.+)\.vcx$| } @vcx_files;

    # Find all text files to search, right in this folder
    my @files = File::Find::Rule ->
        maxdepth(1)->file->name('*.txt')->in($dir);

    foreach my $file (@files)
    {
        open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";
        <$fh>;  # drop the header line
        # Get the second field on each line (with SampleName)
        my @samples = map { (split)[1] } <$fh>;

        # ... search @samples for @names ...
     }
}
```

It is fine to use `glob` for non-recursive searches above, but given its treatment of spaces better use core [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) replacement for it.

There are other ways to organize traversal of directories and file searches,  and there are many ways to compare two lists. Please clarify the overall objective so that I can add suitable code to search `.vcx` names vs. file content.

Please add checks, fix variable names, implement your policies for when things fail, etc.

Comment: Perl can't locate File::Find::Rule module inside the script, however when I type  `perldoc -l File::Find::Rule` in login directory it gives me a path: `/usr/local/share/perl5/File/Find/Rule.pm` When do I need to install the module? I've also tried sudo cpan File::Find::Rule.

Comment: @user3781528  That's strange -- the first thing indicates that the module is installed, and on the system path. (Is that where all modules are?) It may be something about how your environment is setup. Try to include that library path explicitely in the script, with `use lib ...`;  See [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) -- but also search SO posts, to solve it fully.

Comment: @user3781528  Why not try `perldoc -l` on some of the modules you _can_ use in a script and check where they are.  Perhaps it's some other place and you need to add `/usr/local/share/perl5` to `@INC`. That would be a surprise to me but it would result in what you say while it is simple to try.

Comment: @user3781528 Your other question and our exchange there cleared this up -- you need: `use lib '/usr/local/share/perl5';` at the top of the script. Then let me know whether more in this answer would be helpful.